# Copying local files to Hadoop but couldn't succeed

Tags: hadoop, file-io

I tried to copy a local file from hard disk directly to Hadoop directory and got the following results. None of them work. Can anyone help me with the right syntax?

```
$ hadoop fs -copyFromLocal C:\\\temp\\\sample_file.txt /user/user_name/sample_file.txt
**copyFromLocal: unexpected URISyntaxException**

$ hadoop fs -copyFromLocal C://temp//sample_file.txt /user/user_name    /sample_file.txt
**copyFromLocal: `//sample_file.txt': No such file or directory**

$ hadoop fs -copyFromLocal C:\temp\sample_file.txt /user/user_name/sample_file.txt
**-copyFromLocal: Can not create a Path from a null string Usage: hadoop fs [generic options] -copyFromLocal [-f] [-p] ...** 

$ hadoop fs -copyFromLocal C:/temp/sample_file.txt /user/user_name/sample_file.txt
**copyFromLocal: `/temp/sample_file.txt': No such file or directory**
```

Comment: Your entire life and of everyone around you will be made 1000x easier if you move to a sensible operating system.  In other words, I doubt you can get this to work with Windows.

Answer (score 0):

One problem I've encountered when doing a fs -copyFromLocal /localpath/localfile /hdfspath/hdfsfile is when the target /hdfspath doesn't exist.

I usually create the entire target hdfspath first: fs -mkdir /hdfspath, then issue the -copyFromLocal command.

Beyond that, take a look at this bug:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-10030 which seems to explain your first error.
Perhaps your version of hadoop/hdfs doesn't have this fix.

Also according to this blog (http://www.hindoogle.com/blog/2009/12/cygwin-vs-hadoop-dfs-copy/) your first syntax seems to work for them:

`$ bin/hadoop dfs -copyFromLocal C:\\cygwin\\home\\Rajat\\java\\mrh\\input input`